# General proof of independence of TM and TE modes in a waveguide

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, mathematical-physics, classical-electrodynamics

In electromagnetic field analysis for a typical waveguide that has a uniform cross section along its axial direction (say $z$), we often describe the E and H fields conveniently in terms of their Transverse Electric (TE) modes, where $H_{z}\neq 0$ and $E_{z}=0$, or Transverse Magnetic (TM) modes, where $E_{z}\neq 0$ and $H_{z}=0$. All field components can then be derived from our knowledge of $H_{z}$ and $E_{z}$, which are found by solving the wave equation under the given boundary conditions. For example, the transverse vector field components (i.e. in $xy$ cross section) are given in terms of $H_{z}$ and $E_{z}$ (from Maxwell's equations) as:

$$ \boldsymbol{E_{t}}=\frac{-\gamma}{\beta_{c}^{2}}\text{grad}E_z+\frac{Z_{0}\gamma_{0}}{\beta^{2}_{c}} [\hat{k}\times \text{grad}(H_{z})],$$

$$ \boldsymbol{H_{t}}=\frac{-\gamma}{\beta_{c}^{2}}\text{grad}E_z-\frac{\gamma_{0}}{Z_{0}\beta^{2}_{c}} [\hat{k}\times \text{grad}E_{z}],$$

where $\gamma$ is the complex propagation coefficient, $Z$ is the wave impedance and $\beta_{c}$ is the cut-off wavenumber. Zero subscript denotes free-space values, and $\hat{k}$ is the unit vector along $z$.

My question here is how can we prove mathematically that the two longitudinal fields $E_{z}$ (in TM) and $H_{z}$ (in TE) are independent from each other **in general**, to make sure that the modes they each describe are separate sets of modes?
By "general" here I mean that it doesn't build on specific cases or prior physical assumptions about the orthogonality of these modes. That is, a proof that starts only from Maxwell equations and the the simple assumption that the solution can be written in the form:

$$\boldsymbol{E}=(\boldsymbol{E_{t}}+\hat{k}E_{z})e^{i\omega t-\gamma z} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \boldsymbol{H}=(\boldsymbol{H_{t}}+\hat{k}H_{z})e^{i\omega t-\gamma z},$$

with wave equations being:
$$\nabla^{2}E_{z}+\beta^{2}_{c}E_{z}=0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \  \nabla^{2}H_{z}+\beta^{2}_{c}H_{z}=0$$

Comment: Both $H_z$ and $E_z$ satisfy  the Helmholtz equation but with different boundary conditions: Neumann and Dirichlet. resp., so the solutions are independent from each other, whatever "independence" may mean in your question.

Comment: @hyportnex By independent I mean not being possibly linear combinations of each other, so they cannot be derived from each other by superposition, and their respective modes will form different sets that do not couple in a linear medium. When we usually say that the modes in a waveguide in general are made up of TM and TE modes, it implies that they are independent groups. How can we prove this mathematically? For example, can you prove that fields resulting from the same wave equation but different boundary conditions, one Neumann and the other Dirichlet, are linearly independent?

Comment: I do not have a general proof but if you think of circular waveguides then the eigenvalues are different, if you think of rectangular waveguides then you will have sines vs. cosines, etc.